# File I/O to create exercise set with tasks package: missing \item

Tags: expl3, external-files, tasks

**Background:** I'm attempting to use some exercises from an open text that are distributed across many files.  I've rewritten the input mechanism and have it working fine.  I can use `multicols` and `enumerate` to print exercise sets vertically across two columns, but would like to print them horizontally, thus the `tasks` package. The problem is as follows:

**Problem:** When changing from `enumerate` to `tasks`, I'm getting a `missing \item` error.  I assume that this is due to a `\par` introduced somewhere in the I/O operations being included in a `\task` (the `tasks` package documentation lists this as one way that the environment differs from `enumerate`, no `\par`'s allowed).  If this is the case, then I can't find where it's introduced. If not, then I have no idea what's going on.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{numbers_20.tex}
{$5 - (2+3)$}
{$0$}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{numbers_21.tex}
{$5 - (2-3)$}
{$6$}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{numbersset.tex}
\exinput{numbers_20.tex}
\exinput{numbers_21.tex}
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \l__exread_ior % read exercise
\ior_new:N \l__exsetread_ior % read exercise set
\ior_new:N \l__allread_ior % read all

%Relevant code below
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentCommand{\exinput}{m}{
    \ior_open:Nn \l__exread_ior {#1} % open exercise file
    \ior_get:NN \l__exread_ior \l_tmpb_tl % get line
    \task\l_tmpb_tl % add task
    \ior_close:N \l__exread_ior
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\exsetinput}{m}{
    \ior_open:Nn \l__exsetread_ior {#1} % open set file
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \l__exsetread_ior {\seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {##1}} % put exercises in a sequence
    % if following changed to enumerate, and line 31 to item then works as expected.
    \begin{tasks}(2) % start tasks
        % seq items are "exinput" (above) and should print \task\blah
        \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {}
    \end{tasks}

    \ior_close:N \l__exsetread_ior 
    \seq_clear:N \l_tmpb_seq
}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\exsetinput{numbersset}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `tasks` environment does not work quite like `enumerate`. `enumerate` is a "traditional" environment, in the sense that it executes the code line by line until finding its end. `tasks` works more like a command, grabbing the contents of the environment and then doing its thing.

The environment grabs its body and then splits it at each occurrence of the token `\task`. However in your code there is no such token; all there is is `\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {}`.

To make it work with `tasks` you need to first read everything in and put it with explicit `\task` tokens in the body of the environment and then start the `tasks` environment.

I changed your code to do so. It uses a temporary sequence `\l__exread_tmp_seq` (avoid using `\l_tmpa_seq` and other such variables; they are meant for really short term usage, like quick tests) to store the read exercises. It then reads in the file (`numbersset.tex`) without any special treatment. This file should contain the file names to be read, one per line.

The code iterates at each line of the file and uses `\__exread_input_one:Nn` (I made it a private function; you don't need to use it in every line of the file, the code does it for you :-) in each line. This inner function also iterates on each line of each file and appends that line to a sequence variable. Once all of that is done, the sequence should contain all the lines in all the files listed in `numbersset.tex`, each of them preceded by a `\task` token.

Once that is done, the function `x`-expands `\seq_use:Nn \l__exread_tmp_seq { }` before starting the `tasks` environment. Once the environment starts, everything is in its due place and `tasks` does its thing:

> [image]

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{numbers_20.tex}
{$5 - (2+3)$}
{$0$}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{numbers_21.tex}
{$5 - (2-3)$}
{$6$}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{numbersset.tex}
numbers_20.tex
numbers_21.tex
\end{filecontents*}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \l__exread_all_ior
\ior_new:N \l__exread_one_ior
\seq_new:N \l__exread_tmp_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__exread_input_one:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \ior_open:Nn \l__exread_one_ior {#2}
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \l__exread_one_ior
      { \seq_put_right:Nn #1 { \task ##1 } }
    \ior_close:N \l__exread_one_ior
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \exsetinput } { m }
  {
    \seq_clear:N \l__exread_tmp_seq
    \file_if_exist:nTF {#1}
      {
        \ior_open:Nn \l__exread_all_ior {#1}
        \ior_map_inline:Nn \l__exread_all_ior
          { \__exread_input_one:Nn \l__exread_tmp_seq {##1} }
        \ior_close:N \l__exread_all_ior
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn { exread } { file-not-found } {#1} }
    \use:x
      {
        \exp_not:N \begin{tasks}(2)
          \seq_use:Nn \l__exread_tmp_seq { }
        \exp_not:N \end{tasks}
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { exread } { file-not-found }
  { File~`#1'~not~found. }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\exsetinput{numbersset}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks Phelype!